# PyCharm output error messages interspersed with console output. How to fix this?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm running PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.4

Does anyone know why the error messages don't display after the console output?

Thanks

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "F:/Google Drive/code/python_scripts/leetcode/lc_127_word_ladder.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
START
  File "F:/Google Drive/code/python_scripts/leetcode/lc_127_word_ladder.py", line 68, in <module>

    print sol.ladderLength('talk', 'tail', set)
Graph:
  File "F:/Google Drive/code/python_scripts/leetcode/lc_127_word_ladder.py", line 54, in ladderLength
hall ['fall']
    for item in graph[node[0]]:
fall ['hall']
KeyError: 'talk'
End Graph:

Visited =  {'talk': 0}


Node =  ['talk', 0]
Queue Before =  deque([])

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If you'll notice, print statements such as `START`, `Graph:`, `hall ['fall']`, up to `Queue Before = deque([])` all happen within the functioning part of my code. The Error messages should appear after all this.

Comment: It's a common problem, it should work if you start the script again. I think PyCharm handles exceptions and the regular output differently which might be the cause of this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I rerun the script, some different permutation of the lines occurs. What do you mean by "start the script again"?

Comment: I meant to run it again.

Comment: Ah, ok. Guess I'll just have to wait for updated software then. The rest of the environment is great.

Comment: I've filed this as PY-16143 (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16143)

Comment: Thanks for asking. Now at least I know I'm crazy

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by PyCharm mixing print statements from stdout and stderr. There's a fix if you add the following line to your `idea.properties` file:

```
output.reader.blocking.mode=true
```

Get to `idea.properties` via Help | Edit Custom Properties.

Comment: Thank you! This should be the top answer!

Comment: NOT working :(  I just tried it in version 2019.2.2 Community, and the "fix" did absolutely nothing!  
I found a thread on the JetBrains (the manufacturer of PyCharm) site, where users have continually asked them to fix this very annoying issue since 2012!  A whopping 7 YEARS LATER, this issue is still unresolved!!!  :o https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-70016?_ga=2.101984513.1683067021.1577601168-33066029.1577601168  
The thread claims that in the upcoming version 2019.3, "stdout and stderr process streams will influence less each other."   We'll see!

Comment: Wow, that is hilarious. I just realized I created this issue 5 years ago. This single post is responsible for most of my stack overflow "karma" haha

Comment: And it appears that recent releases of PyCharm have broken this fix .

Comment: This issue appeared to me after upgrading Python 3.8 to Python 3.9 when running code. Debugging code made it appear in the correct order. This fixed the run mode.

Answer (score 2):

might just be an issue with the stdout.

a workaround would be to use sys.flush.stdout() after your print statements.

```
import sys

do_something()
print("Your print statement")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to pycharm, so not sure if there's a clean way to do this. But as a workaround, you could replace your print function with a custom one that sleeps quickly after printing, then your traceback should appear after your outputs.

```
import time
print = (lambda p: lambda *args,**kwargs: [p(*args,**kwargs), time.sleep(.01)])(print)



'''
# the above is just a one liner equivalent to this decorator
def add_sleep(p):
    def new_p(*args, **kwargs):
        p(*args,**kwargs)
        time.sleep(.01)
    return new_p
print = add_sleep(print)
'''
```