# Running the same exact trivial code, with a trivial (on purpose) bug, produces the traceback sometimes before a print output and sometimes after

Tags: python, pycharm, traceback

The code in question:

```
print('s')
y=1/0
```

In which I understand the error perfectly (it's just division by zero), causes, when ran (while on PyCharm, by pressing shift+f10, the normal way) either the following output:

```
C:\Users\myname\PycharmProjects\test1\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\myname\PycharmProjects\test1\Functions\error.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\PycharmProjects\test1\Functions\error.py", line 2, in <module>
    y=1/0
      ~^~
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
s

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Or this one (and now note that the printed 's' appears before the traceback instead of after:

```
C:\Users\myname\PycharmProjects\test1\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\myname\PycharmProjects\test1\Functions\error.py 
s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\PycharmProjects\test1\Functions\error.py", line 2, in <module>
    y=1/0
      ~^~
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is a bug. I have had this issue in programs with many more statements and sometimes the traceback is hidden before them.

I tried searching [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014357/pycharm-output-error-messages-interspersed-with-console-output-how-to-fix-this), but they don't focus on if it's important or not the order shown of the output if there is a traceback, and don't have so simple errors, and they are older.

Comment: There's [a 4-years-old bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37396) for precisely this bug, though [a much older one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-70016) was marked as "fixed". Having said that, I don't think this question have anything new compared to the linked one, since the error type is most probably irrelevant and the order is the main problem in not just this one but *both*. If you think an old question needs some attention, we have [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some cursory research leads me to believe this is indeed a bug in PyCharm (and is seemingly pervasive throughout the rest of JetBrains' IDEs) relating to how `stdout` and `stderr` are printed.

GitHub user [`@wolph`](https://github.com/wolph), owner of [the `python-progressbar` project](https://github.com/wolph/python-progressbar), [stated it](https://github.com/wolph/python-progressbar/issues/115#issuecomment-440095729) more eloquently than I can:

> The bug within PyCharm is with the timing between stderr and stdout which appears fully random causing interleaved results.

There have been [multiple](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-70016/error-mixing-stdout-stderr) [reports](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-2400) of this bugged behavior in [JetBrains' publicly-facing bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/) made over the past 12 years. Some of those which are (seemingly) related are still marked "Open":

- [Debugger: stdout/stderr synchronization](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-2135/Debugger-stdout-stderr-synchronization)
- [OCUnit: synchronize stderr/stdout](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-2400)

Even so, JetBrains employee Sergey Simonchik [provided a potential workaround in 2019](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-70016/error-mixing-stdout-stderr#focus=Comments-27-3733711.0-0):

> Please note that proper ordering between `stdout` and `stderr` is still not guaranteed by default, but there is a way to enforce it with `run.processes.with.redirectedErrorStream` registry key. To enable it, do the following:
>
> - "Help | Find Action..." on the main menu; find "Registry..." item and open it;
> - Enable `run.processes.with.redirectedErrorStream` key.
>
> Enabling it will merge `stdout` and `stderr` streams of processes spawned by IDE. This will ensure proper ordering of messages from stdout/stderr.
>
> [...]
>
> However, as a price, merging `stdout` and `stderr` will make them indistinguishable: error output will be printed as normal text. Use ANSI coloring to highlight error output differently.
>
> Please note that the registry key is supported for requested run/debug configurations only. If it is not supported for your run/debug configuration, please submit a request in issue tracker.

---

Given the bug's prevalence after >=12 years of reports, it doesn't seem like this is a very high priority for JetBrains to fix. If this functionality is important for you to get right in your project (and the above workaround doesn't work in your case, for whatever reason), I'd personally recommend evaluating another IDE. There is a litany to choose from.